# Testing VSTO Add-In using UI-Automation

Tags: excel, automated-tests, vsto, ui-automation, office-addins

I have developed a VSTO add-in for Word, Excel  & PowerPoint. Now i want to test the application. Basically i have 100 different test cases to execute for each product (word, Excel, PowerPoint). So i would like to automate this process. Almost all of the test case would look like below.

1. Open Word
2. Type Something
3. Click the "Function 1" (or any other) button of the add-in (Function 1 is basically a toggle button)
4. Save the document
5. Re-Open the document and confirm if the "Function 1" button is still toggled on.

Can anyone suggest any Free/Opensource tools which i can use to automate the test?

Answer (score 0):

'White' is a UI Automation driver: https://github.com/TestStack/White

There's a nice introduction here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/289028/White-An-UI-Automation-tool-for-windows-applicatio

Comment: Does it support VSTO? can I test Excel addin with it?